# Flexbox Vertical/horizontally Align Child Elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

Trying to learn Flexbox, So if I wanted something vertically and horizontally center aligned but I also wanted something else within the parent element to be aligned to the top left corner of the page, would I use two containers or is there a way to vertically and horizontally align child elements? I'm so confused.

I appreciate any replies.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Elements Website</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover.css" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>

      <div class='container'>

         <div class='content'>

          <img alt="" width="400" src="image/box1.svg" class="button hvr-grow">

      </div>

    </div>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
body{

background-color: azure;
background-size: cover;
height:100vh;

}

.container{

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
min-height:100vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}


.content{



}

.boxorange{



}
```

Comment: This may help you figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it.

Comment: Can you provide desired result ? (image or something). Dont understand what you're asking